# Capture screenshot of a specific window (macOS)

Tags: node.js, macos

Is there a way using NodeJS to capture a screenshot of a specific window?
Let's say I have my Chrome app open, and I want the screenshot of just this window, or a screenshot of the desktop (even if there are other windows covering it).

I was looking for some solution but the packages I found (e.g. `screenshot-desktop`) capture the whole screen, so if a specific window is hidden, there is no way for me to capture it.